# Can I get a data race from numpy?

Tags: numpy, simulation, game-physics

I'm trying to write a basic rope simulation using `numpy`. However, it oscillates and explodes.

One theory is that there might be a data race.

The edges are stored as an `(2,N)` array on integers, which refer to the indices of the vertices.

Some steps of my code do matrix operations on these indices, making it possible that the same vertex could be referred to twice. Would this create a data race? here is an example

`constraintpositions[edges[:,1]] -= edgevertexdeltasweighted`

And my whole script is here

```py
import bpy
import numpy as np
import time

mesh_object = bpy.context.active_object

# Initialise timestep (seconds), vertex weight (kg), gravity
timestep = 0.5
weight = 0.05
gravity = np.array([0,0,-9.8])

# Ensure it's a mesh and convert to numpy arrays
if mesh_object and mesh_object.type == 'MESH':
    mesh = mesh_object.data
    
    # Extract vertex coordinates as NumPy array
    length = len(mesh.vertices)
    positions = np.empty(length*3, dtype=np.float64)
    mesh.vertices.foreach_get('co', positions)
    positions.shape = (length, 3)
    
    # Extract edges as NumPy array
    edgelength = len(mesh.edges)
    edges = np.empty(edgelength*2, dtype=np.uint8)
    mesh.edges.foreach_get('vertices', edges)
    edges.shape = (edgelength, 2)

    # get edge lengths
    edgelengthsstart = np.empty(edgelength, dtype = np.float64)
    edgevectors = positions[edges[:,1]] - positions[edges[:,0]]
    edgelengthsstart = np.linalg.norm(edgevectors, axis= 1)

    #initialise arrays for distance constraint
    edgevertexdeltas = np.empty((edgelength, 2), dtype = np.float64)
    edgelengthsnew = np.empty(edgelength, dtype = np.float64)
    constraintpositions = np.zeros_like(positions)


else:
    print("Please select a valid mesh object.")


#initialise velocities
velocities = np.zeros_like(positions)
#print(velocities)

def update(velocities, positions, timestep, weight, gravity):

    #Update velocities and positions
    newpositions=np.copy(positions)
    velocities+= timestep*weight*gravity
    newpositions += timestep*velocities

    # calculate constraints

    for i in range (1,4):
        #v1, v2 = 
        edgevectorsnew = newpositions[edges[:,1]] - newpositions[edges[:,0]]
        edgelengthsnew = np.linalg.norm(edgevectorsnew, axis= 1)
        edgedifferences = edgelengthsnew - edgelengthsstart
        edgeratios = edgedifferences/edgelengthsnew
        #print(edgeratios)
        edgevertexdeltasweighted = 0.5 * edgevectorsnew * edgeratios[:, np.newaxis]

        #Update constraint positions
        constraintpositions = np.copy(newpositions)
        constraintpositions[edges[:,1]] -= edgevertexdeltasweighted
        constraintpositions[edges[:,0]] += edgevertexdeltasweighted
        newpositions = np.copy(constraintpositions)
        newpositions[0] = [0,0,0]


    #update velocity and positions
    velocities = (1/timestep)*(newpositions-positions)
    positions = np.copy(newpositions)
    #print(positions)

    # Put it back into mesh
    vertexpositions = np.copy(positions)
    vertexpositions.shape = length*3
    mesh.vertices.foreach_set("co", vertexpositions)
    mesh.update()


    return velocities, positions

for i in range(0,2):   
    velocities, positions = update(velocities, positions, timestep, weight, gravity)
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

A version that uses a for loop to iterate over the edges one by one works well, albeit very stretchy.

I'm struggling to see how to vectorise the edge constraints...

Comment: I doubt this is caused by any kind of data race. I think it's because you're using euler's method for solving a differential equation, which can be numerically unstable and does not conserve energy. Does the simulation improve when you try a smaller timestep? you may want to look into other methods to calculate `newpositions`

Comment: Please, post a [mre]. That code is way too big to contain only the necessary step to reproduce the problem. Plus, it relies on a huge library, whose purpose, as far as I understand, is to handle a mesh object that we don't have. So, even with that huge code we can't reproduce it anyway.

Comment: In the meantine, it may be worth noting that `X=np.zeros((3,)); X[[0,1,0,0,1]]+=1` makes `X` `[1,1,0]` not, `[3,2,0]`. So, the code line you are mentioning may be not doing what you expect, if `edges` contains duplicates index. But that would not qualify as a "data race". It is just how it is supposed to work. Not some numpy thread threading over some other concurrent threads.

Comment: This is a blender script so if you have a mesh selected (i used a string of vertices) and paste this into the script editor and run it it would show you

Comment: I'm not sure why but it seems to work. I was surprised at just how much changing the constraint iterations changes the stretchiness of the mesh. I believe this is a known issue with the PBD model